How to check only that objects are inherited from an abstract class
export class GameScene extends Layer<GameSceneEvents> {
    test() {
    }
}

layers: Record<string, Layer<any>> = {
        gameScene: new GameScene(),
        winnScene: new WinnScene(),
};

i have error

TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Layer'.

I don't want to do this
(this.layers.gameScene as GameScene).test();

How to correctly specify the type?
It work if remove 'Record<string, Layer>' (thanks @Blackhole)
but how to set this type manually?
Example
because if we ignore this and remove the type from Layer, we will get further problems
Object.keys(layers).forEach((key:string)=>{
            layers[key].test()
});

Example 2

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
'string' can't be used to index type '{ gameScene: GameScene;
winnScene: WinnScene; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of
type 'string' was found on type '{ gameScene: GameScene; winnScene:
WinnScene; }'.

My Way but it not good
 layers:{[index: string]:any} = {
        gameScene: new GameScene(),
        winnScene: new WinnScene(),
    };

All Code
   export abstract class Layer<T extends string> {
    container = [];
    eventEmitter = [];
}

type WinnSceneEvents = "test";
export class WinnScene extends Layer<GameSceneEvents> {
    test() {
      console.log("test");
    }
}

type GameSceneEvents = "test";
export class GameScene extends Layer<GameSceneEvents> {
    test() {
      console.log("test");
    }
}

const layers = {
        gameScene: new GameScene(),
        winnScene: new WinnScene(),
};

layers.gameScene.test();

Object.keys(layers).forEach((key:string)=>{
            layers[key].test()
});


By specifying the type, you lose the information about the inherited class. Let TypeScript do it for you: layers = {gameScene: …};. If you want to be sure that members are indeed of type Layer, do it without casting, with the satisfies operator: layers = {gameScene: …} satisfies Record<string, Layer<any>>;

@Blackhole if do u mean GameScene|WinnScene it looks not good

No, I mean that you have to remove the explicit type declaration: Record<string, Layer<any>>.

@Blackhole oh it work but how setup manual this

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to immediately see the issue you're talking about. (right now this is just an excerpt that doesn't have the declarations we need to see anything but errors).   It's possible you just want satisfies as mentioned by @Blackhole, but without a [mre] we can't test anything ourselves.

I'm not sure to understand your question. Can you reformulate and elaborate, eventually by editing your initial post?

@Blackhole updated thanks for the way

Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself. Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. I'd be happy to do it myself if you prefer (but since the code isn't mine I don't necessarily have license to copy it without your permission)

The problem with Object.keys() is something totally distinct; you'll find more information (and potential solutions) here. In this case, a type assertion is indeed necessary.

Will all the classes that extend from Layer have the same methods? Your example suggests they would, but not sure if that's intentional
